# Ruby Rails Active Record Query on two columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say we have following table:
Employee
**ID Name Sick_Leaves Casual_Leaves

1  John   4           8

2 Nancy   5           2

3  Matthew 2          9**

Now if I want to get a list of all the Employess who have taken more sick leaves than casual, its straight forward in SQL:
**Select * from Employee Where Sick_Leaves > Casual_Leave**

Now considering that I have a Rails Active Record Model class defined for Employee, how can I execute the same query using model class itself ? I am getting stuck in how to define the WHERE clause. If it had been Sick_Leaves > 5 (or some fixed number), then its simple, but what now when we want to compare two columns itself ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails' interface to Active Relation doesn't have a simple syntax for expressing "greater than" (amongst other things). So you can either use hand-written SQL (as @JKen12579 suggested) or you can step down into the bowels of using ARel syntax. (It's weird at first but gives you the full power of SQL still.)

```
Employee.where(arel_table[:Sick_Leaves].gt(arel_table[:Casual_Leaves]))
```

I'd recommend this approach because it keeps you writing Ruby code, it alleviates issues with having to write the table name or not (e.g. "Do I need to use `employees.<column>`?"), and it is database agnostic (which may not be important here but maybe later... so get used to the syntax and never worry).

Comment: Ok, lets say if I relax the requirement of greater than, i.e. we need sick_leaves = casual_leaves, then can we do that through code rather than hard coding column names ?

Comment: Would have to do the same as above but with `.eq()` instead of `.gt()`.

Comment: Am I missing something? This is doing it through code. Are you looking to do this in a Ruby array? Such as `my_arary.select { |e| e.sick_leaves > e.casual_leaves }`? Or are you wanting a SQL/database query still?

Comment: Nope, this sounds good. I did not know about ARel syntax. May be this would help me here. Actually I want to do this on an INNER JOIN result where first column is from first table and second column to compare is from other table which is being joined.

Comment: You may appreciate this talk from Rails Conf: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShPAxNcLm3o

Comment: Also check out the [arel gem page](https://github.com/rails/arel) because you can do a lot with arel in rails... also note that the answer in this case assumes a self in front of arel_table so its operating on the Employee class. You mention you're looking do do a join, which will require different syntax

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following ActiveRecord query:

```
Employee.where('sick_leaves > casual_leaves')
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would prefer a solution in which I dont use a hand written SQL.